# Huffman Encoding C++ code is throwing a fatal error

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I am writing a code for famous algorithm Huffman Encoding. I am getting a fatal error which turn system into blue screen and then restart. This error occurs in display_Codes which have recursive calls. The error occurs on the following lines:

```
display_Codes(root->l, s + "0"); 
display_Codes(root->r, s + "1" );
```

Following is the complete code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bits/stdc++.h> 

using namespace std;




class HeapNode_Min {




public:


char d; 

unsigned f; 

HeapNode_Min *l, *r;
HeapNode_Min(char d, unsigned f) 
{ 

      this->d = d;
      this->f = f;
}




~HeapNode_Min()
 {
   delete l;
   delete r;
 } 
}; 



class Analyze {  

  public:
    bool operator()(HeapNode_Min* l, HeapNode_Min* r) 
    { 
        return (l->f > r->f);
    } 
}; 



void display_Codes(HeapNode_Min* root, string s) 
{   
    if(!root) 
        return; 

    if (root->d != '$') 
        cout << root->d << " : " << s << "\n";

    display_Codes(root->l, s + "0"); 
    display_Codes(root->r, s + "1" ); 

} 

void HCodes(char data[], int freq[], int s) 
{ 
    HeapNode_Min  *t,*r, *l ;  


    priority_queue<HeapNode_Min*, vector<HeapNode_Min*>, Analyze> H_min; 

    int a=0;
    while (a<s){H_min.push(new HeapNode_Min(data[a], freq[a])); ++a;}


    while (H_min.size() != 1) { 

        l = H_min.top(); H_min.pop(); 
        r = H_min.top(); H_min.pop(); 

        t = new HeapNode_Min('$',  r->f + l->f); 

        t->r = r; t->l = l; 


        H_min.push(t); 
    } 
    display_Codes(H_min.top(), ""); 
} 



int main() 
{ 
    try
    {

        int frequency[] = { 3, 6, 11, 14, 18, 25 };  char alphabet[] = { 'A', 'L', 'O', 'R', 'T', 'Y' };  
        int size_of = sizeof(alphabet) / sizeof(alphabet[0]); 

      cout<<"Alphabet"<<":"<<"Huffman Code\n";
      cout<<"--------------------------------\n";

      HCodes(alphabet, frequency, size_of);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I recommend doing a bit of research to find out what `#include <bits/stdc++.h> ` does and then never using it again.

Comment: The fatal error may contain useful information like [magic debug codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_debug_values) you can use to help diagnose the problem. In this case an you may see the program crashing over an address of 0xbaadfood which the linked wiki page lists as a common value used to fill uninitialized dynamic memory.

Comment: What OS are you running where an apparent common programming error results in a blue screen and forces a reboot?

Comment: I am running Windows 10. The error is kmode exception not handled on blue screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never set `l` or `r` to `nullptr`, but your code relies on the pointers being either valid or `nullptr`:

> ```
> void display_Codes(HeapNode_Min* root, string s) 
> {   
>     if(!root) 
>         return; 
>
>     if (root->d != '$') 
>         cout << root->d << " : " << s << "\n";
>
>     display_Codes(root->l, s + "0"); 
>     display_Codes(root->r, s + "1" ); 
>
> }
> ```

Pass a `root` with no left and no right node, then neither `root->l` nor `root->r` have a value that you could use for anything. Passing them to the next recursion lets you dereference them which invokes undefined behavior.

To fix that you need to initialize the pointers, eg in the constructor:

```
HeapNode_Min(char d, unsigned f) : d(d),f(f),l(nullptr),r(nullptr) { }
```

Also your class does not follow the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: plus one for the rule of 3/5/0

Comment: oh great @formerlyknownas_46303 .. your suggestion worked. thanks a lot